# GitHub Action - reusable workflow: installing a python library from repo fails due to missing module

Tags: python, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a reusable workflow where the key part is that it installs a python library.
The Python library required the `packaging` module to be installed, so before that it installs said module. This reusable workflow used to be a composit, however, it requirements suited it better as a reusable module, so it got changed. When that changed happend, it stopped working.

```yaml
name: 'install my_lib'

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      python:
        description: 'python version'
        default: '3.9'
        type: string
    secrets:
      ORG_GH_TOKEN:
        description: 'The github token'
        required: true


jobs:
  setup_build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Python Lib
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: 'ORG/my_python_lib'
          ref: 'main'
          path: "Repo_Folder"
          token: ${{ secrets.ORG_GH_TOKEN }}

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4.3.1
        with:
          python-version: '${{ inputs.python }}'
          check-latest: true
          cache: 'pip'
      
      - name: Install my_lib and version print out
        shell: bash
        run: | 
          python --version
          pip install -r ./Repo_Folder/requirements.txt
          pip install ./Repo_Folder
          python -c 'import my_lib; print(my_lib.__version__)'
```

Running this on anything that uses this reusable workflow, gives me this (cut down full trace error)

```
Python 3.9.16
Collecting packaging==22.0 (from -r ./Repo_Folder/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading packaging-22.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.6/42.6 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: packaging
Successfully installed packaging-22.0

# Trace of error that I skip pasting here, ending up in:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

I have tried using `--no-build-isolation` with pip, that did not help.
I have started converting the python lib over to a pytoml, however, that there are some differetn problems in doing that. As I am using the `setup-python` action, I tried with and without cache.

Any idea in why this happens, and suggestions for a solution?

Comment: _This reusable workflow used to be a composite_: Do you have the composite `action.yaml` file to compare both behaviors?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes I do. Thanks to the power of git. I have uploaded it here on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/WGnw9xXx

Comment: It looks like you pasted the code from the workflow question to the composite `action.yaml` in the link. How did you resolved the `Repo_Folder` there? And the other `actions/checkout` inputs variables? What it all hardcoded?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I am not certain what you are asking. I made the old composite 'action.yaml' to a reusable workflow. The inputs are just the Github token (that should have been a secret in composite version) and python version that default is 3,9. Both of the different workflow seem to pull the repo fine into the `Repo_Folder`. The `Repo_Folder` has no action. Just a plane python library that.

Comment: I just wanted to check if the behavior was different, because the reusable workflow will run in a new runner each time, whenever a composite action will run in the job runner where you're calling the action (with other steps). So even if both scenarios seem similar, there are some details that might be impacting what you're expecting to happen here.